# How to reference structure components in C++

Tags: c++, class, reference, struct

Sorry for the novice question, but I want to reference components of a class/struct type to pass as parameters in a function. I don't know whether to use

```
blah.memberFunction(&blah.component)
```

or

```
blah.memberFunction((&blah).component)
```

Comment: Do you want to pass a pointer or a reference?

Comment: If you're using C++11, consider a lambda: [](T blah){ return blah.component; }

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your member function looks like this:

```
blah::memberFunction(blahType& component)
```

Calling it is this:

```
blah.memberFunction(blah.component)
```

Use of the `&` operator gives you a pointer, which is different from a reference. References don't need operators.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referenig to class components as [data members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10cwk72y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)? In the specific case that you are talking about: calling a method using the member as parameter is useless in most cases. Consider the code:

```
class blah
{
public:
  blah() : component(0) {}
  void  memberFunction() { component ++; }
  int component;
}

int main()
{
   blah b;
   std::cout << b.component; //output = 0
   b.memberFunction();
   std::cout << b.component; //output =1
}
```

Notice that in a class method I already have access to the data member: Why should I use it as a parameter for it's own method, doesn't it sound kinda useless?

Anyway, if you REALLY have a good reason to implement it using a reference to a member, than just declare the method to [receive arguments by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/):

```
class blah
{
public:
    blah() : component(0) {}
    void callMemberFunction() 
    {
        memberFunction(component);
    }
    void  memberFunction(int &member_reference) { member_reference++; }

    int component;
}

int main()
{
    blah b;
    std::cout << b.component <<"\n"; //output = 0
    b.callMemberFunction();
    std::cout << b.component <<"\n"; //output =1
}
```